# Remove numbers from a comma separated string in javascript when checked is false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some inputs by type checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="5da1dc651d011c56ef1cb3db_693715"  onchange="handlechange(this)">
<input type="checkbox" value="6da1dc651d011c56ef1cb3db_123689"  onchange="handlechange(this)">
```

`handlechange()` function is going to add the values of input checkedin

```
<input type="hidden" value="" class="GetVals" />
```

The main problem is that when checked is false the value of that input should be removed of `<input type="hidden" value="" class="GetVals" />`, but it would not remove.

```
function handlechange(a) {
  var check = $(a).prop("checked");
  if (check == true) {
    var value = $(a).val();
    ids += value + ','

  } 
  else if (check == false) {
    var elements = ids.substring(0, ids.lastIndexOf(","))
    var element = elements.split(",");
  }
  $(".GetVals").val(ids)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the result by using some built-in methods.

You can use [**`.map()`**](https://api.jquery.com/map/) only on the checked check boxes with [**`.get()`**](https://api.jquery.com/get/) and [**`join()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) like the following way:

```js
function handlechange() {
  var ids = $('input:checked').map((i, chk) => chk.value).get().join();
  $(".GetVals").val(ids)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="5da1dc651d011c56ef1cb3db_693715"  onchange="handlechange(this)">
<input type="checkbox" value="6da1dc651d011c56ef1cb3db_123689"  onchange="handlechange(this)">

<input class="GetVals" style="width:500px;"/>
```

Comment: Beat me to it :-) . BTW, you don't need the parameter `a` anymore & in `onchange="handlechange(this)"`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function handlechange() {
  var ids = [];
  $(".checkbox").each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      ids.push($(this).val());
    }
  });
  $(".GetVals").val(ids.join(","));
  $("#vals").text(ids.join(","));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="5da1dc651d011c56ef1cb3db_693715" onchange="handlechange()">
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="6da1dc651d011c56ef1cb3db_123689" onchange="handlechange()">
<input type="hidden" value="" class="GetVals" />
<div id="vals"></div>
```

You can use `each` to loop the `checkbox` and then `join` all values which are checked.